# Not giving me the return value

Tags: android

I am calling a fuction `validate()` and if the condition is true it should enter into `return` and stay on that page, But when I debug even if the condition is true, its not entering into return. Can anyone help me pease. I have tried a lot and atlast decided to post. Please help

```
 if(balance>0) {

                   final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DetailActivity.this);
                   alertDialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
                   alertDialog.setMessage("Order has been removed successfully.\n\nRepayable Amount is Rs " + balance);

                   final LinearLayout diagLayout = new LinearLayout(OrderDetailsActivity.this);
                   diagLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                   final EditText  text = new EditText(OrderDetailsActivity.this);
                   text.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                   text.setHint("User Pin");
                   text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                   text.setTextSize(20);
                   diagLayout.addView(text);
                   alertDialog.setView(diagLayout);

                   alertDialog.setPositiveButton("REFUND", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                         validate(text);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScreenActivity.class);
                               startActivity(intent);

                       }
                   });

                   alertDialog.setNegativeButton("TO ACCOUNT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                          removeOrder();
                           dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });


                   alertDialog.show();

               }
               else {
                   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OrderDetailsActivity.this);

                   builder.setMessage("Order has been removed successfully")
                           .setTitle("Removed");

                   builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                           dialog.dismiss();
                           finish();
                       }
                   });

                   AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                   dialog.show();
                   hideProgressWheel(true);
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(RPCRequest request, ResponseError error) {
                showAlert(error.getErrorSummary(), error.getErrorTitle());
                hideProgressWheel(true);
            }
        };



        private void validate(EditText text) {
            String pin = text.getText().toString();
            if (pin == null || pin.isEmpty()) {
                showToast("enter user pin");
                return;
            }

        }
```

Comment: not sure about your problem but "return" is not necessary in "validate" method

Comment: Regardless of the validate function you are calling `startActivity(intent);`, if the case is to stay in the page you need to call `startActivity(intent);` within your validate method or return a Boolean from the method and check it and then `startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from `validate()` method, not from positive callback if I have gotten you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just return boolean otherwise there is no use of using return in void as it will return from validate only not from where you are calling

```
 private boolean validate(EditText text) {
        String pin = text.getText().toString();
        if (pin == null || pin.isEmpty()) {
            showToast("enter user pin");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and at calling site check like this

```
if(!validate(text)) return;
```

then it won't go further.

Comment: Thankyou for helping me @vikas kumar. I have tried that..but it shows the progress wheel and when i backpress the item gets cancelled